# DataTabels - How to remove top search bar?

Tags: jquery, django, datatables, searchbar

in datatables there is a search bar on top of the table and there is search bar on each column is it possible to remove the top search bar ?

i know i can use {searching: false} but it will disable searching on each column too i just want to hide/remove the top search bar i want other search bars work properly

here's my js code :

```
$('#table-1').dataTable({paging: false, bDeferRender: true, bProcessing: true});
var table = $('#table-1').dataTable();
$('#table-1 tfoot th').each(function (i) {
    var title = $('#table-1 thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
    var serach = '<input type="text" class="coulmnSearch" placeholder="جستجوی ' + title + '" />';
    $(this).html('');
    $(serach).appendTo(this).keyup(function(){table.fnFilter($(this).val(),i)})
});
```

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/jignesh221290/y3o1hxsv/1/

Comment: @ jignesh patel 
it will disable the search bars on columns too

Comment: $(".dataTables_filter input").off();
  $(".dataTables_filter").css("display", "none");

Comment: see it work at http://live.datatables.net/yubizeku/1/edit   also, for datatables 1.10+ use DataTable (capital d) not dataTable

Comment: @Erfan Check this http://jsfiddle.net/jignesh221290/6y2ws3up/1/

Comment: tnx every one my problem solved i cannot check correct answer here 
but i really appreciate your help 
Thank You